# Howto get sensors work for new motherboards without update-grub

Tags: grub2, lm-sensors

I have bought an X99 series motherboard and I want to have fan speed, motherboard temperature, etc. I've installed **lm-sensors** but it shows only a brief report of CPU temperatures. As it was said in many pages, the solution is to add `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in grub configuration file, update the grub and reboot.

But for some reasons, I can't update my grub. So is there any alternative solution **without the need to update-grub**?

**UPDATE:** I read somewhere in the web that loading some kernel modules relative to `acpi` with the mentioned grub command line would cause some instabilities due to incompatibility with hardware drivers. Is that correct? and if so, is there a better solution to have some acpi monitors without loading these kernel modules?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of - what's preventing you from updating grub ? It might be easier to fix that than trying to find an alternative solution.

Comment: @JonasCz: thanks; I have a diskless cluster and added some new nodes which have x99 chipset. So updating the grub needs some difficulties as nodes don't have any hard disks and they boot via network. also older nodes don't need these modules to be loaded.